# VS debugger does not close

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have the following code. can anyone tell me what would happen to ut, c2 instances? Would they be hanging around without being garbage-collected for a long time? The reason I ask is that after I close all the windows including the one that execute this code Visual Studio debugger is still on (I am running it in debug mode).
If I don't raise exception in Initializer() method in Class2, the debugger will close after I close all the windows.

Below is by code

```
namespace Test
{
  public class Class1
  {

    private ICommand testCommand; 
    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return updCommand ?? (updCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
          int nStatus = 0;
          Class2 c2 = new Class2();
          nStatus = c2.InitStatus;
          if (nStatus == 0)
          {
            c2.doSth()
          }
          System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Return status = " + nStatus.ToString());
          c2 = null;
        }
        ));
      }
    }
  }

  public class Class2
  {
    Utilities ut = new Utilities();
    public int InitStatus { get; set; }

    public Dbupdate()
    {
      Initializer();
    }
    private void Initializer()
    {
      try
      {
        throw new Exception("just test");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { ErrHandler("Initializer(): " + ex.Message); InitStatus = -100; }
    }

    private void doSth()
    {
      ut.doWhateve();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the Application.ShutdownMode of the application?

Comment: where do I look for  Application.ShutdownMode of the application?

Comment: it is not defined in app.xaml So it must be the default OnLastWindowClose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I instantiated a window but didn't close before throwing the exception.